# Copying a Google "Maps" search field to an "Image" search field

Tags: google-search, google-maps, google-image-search

Say I searched for my childhood's school on Google Maps:

[image]

After seeing the "*Earth View*" of it, I feel like searching for Images of this college, on *Google Image* search.

Is there a way to launch an image search with the same input as the one currently used in Google Maps? (Or any other media-specific Google search such as Videos, etc.)

My reasoning is that since I'm gonna go from a Google service to another Google service, there might be a way besides from "copy/paste" to switch search results type.

Otherwise I can copy/paste but that requires selecting the text, going to Google Image search, then pasting, then clicking the "search" button.

Other Google search services have shortcuts to search through different type of media at the top of the page as seen here:

[image]

I tried clicking on different menus and shortcuts, but none that led to a different type of search. Looking for ways to do this on Google didn't give any results either.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a photo in Google Maps, the page footer could show the logo of the Google service that hosts the photo ( Panoramio or Google+) or in the case that the photo is hosted in Street View, in the top left corner a pop-pup will show up, including some controls to navigate through the Street View repository.