# Switch to street view in Google maps search results

Tags: google-maps, street-view

In a past question, I've expressed my [confusion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89639/copying-a-google-maps-search-field-to-an-image-search-field) about Google's behavior when it comes to navigating between search results by type of content (web search, image search, maps search…) - without losing the contents of your search field.

I'm once again surprised: after searching for a type of service in Google search (restaurant, shop…), then clicking on the map, I cannot seem to get street view, while being in a Google Map (I don't necessarily mean to have Street View for one of the proposed locations).

Steps to reproduce:

***1 - Perform a search on Google that will be likely to return a minified map, click on the map:***

[image]

***2 - On the enlarged map view, try to switch to Street View:***

[image]

A Street View shortcut or the little yellow person icon is not there:

[image]

*Note: I know that if I access the website https://www.google.com/maps, I will be able to type a search in the search field and then easily switch to Street View. This is not what I am asking, as most of the time my browser's search bar is set to **Google**, not **Google Maps**.*

Comment: When I tried this, once I clicked on G Street Fabrics in the list of places, pictures were available.  The one with the round arrows was the street view.

Comment: @GaiusAugustus Ok, I see what you're saying. Not always works, look, I clicked on the "Gather" restaurant: http://i.imgur.com/q2jLIZl.jpg

Comment: It's in that image, it just isn't the largest image.  It's the one with the two round arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Google search I did for restaurants near me:

[image: Google search for restaurants near me]

I clicked on the first one.  You can see that it shows you images that people have taken nearby.  As long as there's an address, there should be an image as pointed out below, with two round arrows.

[image: Images]

Here's a closeup.  Once you click that image, it takes you to Street View:

[image: Closeup of Streetview Image]

Comment: But what if from that page you want Street View on "N Palomas Ave"? Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: You could technically go into "Directions" from here, and then the little Street View guy is where you're used to.  Perhaps there's a better way.